# VBA How to use regular expression on a user input in a cell

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to specify the user input in a cell with a regular expression. The idea is to use only these strings:

```
C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9, C10
```

followed by blank space then merge or complete framed or width  and finally followed by blank space and then an integer from 1 to 100.

For example
C4 merge 1, C5 width 2, C7 complete framed. There must be no integer after complete framed and every 3 combinations must be separated with comma.

Until now I found only how to use only specific words and this is the expression:
^(?!\s*$)(?:merge|complete framed|width )+$. Here is my sheet I am working for. Currently I need to do this in column G only:

```
 C6,merge,1,  C10,merge,1, C8,merge,1, C9,merge,1, C1,complete framed,1, C6,merge,1, C2,complete framed,1, C5,complete framed,1, C8,merge,1, C1,complete framed,1, C5,merge,1, C5,merge,1, C8,merge,1, C9,merge,1, C7,merge,1, C2,complete framed,1, C6,merge,1, C1,complete framed,1
C5,merge,1, C8,merge,1, C7,merge,1, C9,merge,1, C6,merge,2, C1,complete framed,2, C7,merge,1, C6,merge,1, C8,merge,1, C6,width,1, C8,width,1
C6,merge,1, C4,merge,1 .
```

The difference now is after "complete framed" there must be no integer

```
 Sub by_blocks_regex()


 Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "\b(C(?:10|[1-9])),(merge|complete framed|width),(\d+)"
 Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
 Dim regEx As New RegExp
 Dim strInput As String
 Dim strOutput As String
 Dim Myrange As Range
 Dim currMatch As match

 Dim cell As Range
 Set Myrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BY Blocks").Range("G3:G19")
 Dim currCell As Range

 For Each currCell In Myrange
     If strPattern <> vbNullString Then
         strInput = currCell.Value
     End If
         With regEx
         .Global = True
         .MultiLine = True
         .IgnoreCase = False
         .Pattern = strPattern

     If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
     strOutput = regEx.Replace(strInput, strPattern)
                    'MsgBox ("A cell match with the pattern:   ") &  currCell
                'Else
                   'MsgBox ("No cell match with the pattern:   ") & strPattern
                End If
   End With
   Next currCell
   End Sub
```

I tested the regular expression and it finds every string in the cells but I can`t figure out how to use the strPattern in a cell input and separate each substring so to allow only valid values like C5 width 1, C4 merge 2. Maybe regex IsMatch method must be used. When the user types some data in the cell to find every allowed match and validate the input data. Anyone with an idea how this should be done?

Comment: It is not quite clear, are you trying to validate the cell values as per the requirements you listed? You say there must be no integer after `complete framed`, but there are numbers after this string in your screenshot. What should be the final result?

Comment: The final result should be for example: C4 merge1, C5 width 2; C9 complete framed-cell validation per the requirements above

Comment: Aha, so you want to reformat the cell values, right?

Comment: Yes,that`s right with a regular expression

Comment: Could you please add the column text as *text* and not as a picture to the question body?

Comment: There must be a space between every value-have to look llike: C3 merge 1, C5 width 6

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to help you if the post is not formatted correctly. Please check your text in the question and the screenshot: line breaks differ, and there are commas in your text version where they are absent in the picture.

Comment: I think now looks fine

Comment: Well, it does not, but it is clear that you have not, but it is clear you are still far from what you need. Probably, you want to write a function that will find a pattern like [`\b(C(?:10|[1-9])),(merge|complete framed|width),(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Uysejr/2) and then insert spaces between the groups unless Group 2 is `complete framed`, then the third group value will be omitted.

Comment: Ok I will try this expression ans see the result

Comment: It won't work as is, you should add some logic to it. Please post the code once you get stuck with this pattern implementation.

Comment: Ok, I will post it later

Comment: Your examples are different.  You say _every 3 combinations must be separated with comma_, but your examples are `C6,merge,1, C4,merge,1`.  Shouldn't it be `C6 merge 1, C4 merge 1`?

Comment: Yes, exactly this should be

Comment: This should be `C6,merge,1, C4,merge,1`, or this should be `C6 merge 1, C4 merge 1`?

Comment: C6 merge 1, C4 merge 1

Comment: Good, the answer I'm about to post will work then. :)

Comment: Ok, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will check each set of three combinations when you update a cell.  Paste the code in the worksheet rather than a module.  It assumes your text follows the rule of:

> every 3 combinations must be separated with comma

For example, the string `C6 merge 1, C4 merge 1` will have `C6 merge 1` and `C4 merge 1` checked. It ignores the comma and leading/trailing spaces.

**Note:** I haven't checked the RegExp pattern as that's not my forte, but it checks as you enter the data in column G.  Maybe post a separate question to get the correct Reg Exp syntax?

You may want to create the `RegEx` variable with a worksheet scope that gets initialised when the sheet is activated and destroyed when you leave the sheet (save having to do it each time you update a cell).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim regEx As RegExp
    Dim vValues As Variant
    Dim vValue As Variant

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
        strPattern = "\b(C(?:10|[1-9])),(merge|complete framed|width),(\d+)"
        Set regEx = New RegExp

        vValues = Split(Target, ",")

        With regEx
            For Each vValue In vValues
                '.Global = True 'Not needed as possible matches are passed one at a time using Split.
                '.MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern

                If .Test(Trim(vValue)) Then
                    MsgBox "Match found in " & Target.Value & " : " & Trim(vValue)
                Else
                    MsgBox "No match"
                End If
            Next vValue
        End With
    End If  

    Set regEx = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: But can I ask you if we check the regex pattern , is this be more suitable for this solution because I also want to validate the cell input to match only this pattern - so only the cell must include values from C1 to C10, the above words in the pattern and integers from 1 to 100. I checked the pattern and it is ok

Comment: And in this case when we have a match because I tried many inputs and everytime I get "No match"

Comment: I can't get the pattern to work.  I've tried both `^(?!\s*$)(?:merge|complete framed|width )+$` as you originally wrote, I've tried `\b(C(?:10|[1-9])),(merge|complete framed|width),(\d+)` as appears in your code and neither returns a match for `C4 merge 1` or `C5 width 2` or `C9 complete framed`.  As I said in my answer _I haven't checked the RegExp pattern as that's not my forte_ - I can say it's not finding the patterns you've suggested as examples so far.

Comment: Ok, maybe the syntax is wrong, I asked another question about that. Thanks!

Comment: @user3701825 I doubt that is "another" question. `.MultiLine = True` makes no sense here, it can be removed. This `MsgBox` thing is of no help at all.

Comment: Darren, OP does not need to test the values against my regex. OP needs to reformat the values according to the rules explained in the question.

Comment: The question is what will be the correct syntax of this regex cause until now it doesn`t match the values needed. I tried a few more patterns but none of them was useful

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew.  Yes, sorry,  `.MultiLine=TRUE` should be removed.  The `MsgBox` is just so I know it's found the value - would be useless in the final code.  I don't think the OP needs to reformat their values - they know what value they're after so the pattern must be wrong.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook If OP did not want to re-format the values, why use `regEx.Replace(strInput, strPattern)`? My pattern is neither wrong nor right, the question is still rather unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  lol, fair play. Got carried away trying to get the pattern correct and forgot the purpose of the code.  That's confusing me now though - for instance, on the first loop `currCell = G3 ("C6 merge 1")`.  `strPattern` will never be `vbNullString`, so `strInput` will always be = `currCell` ("C6 merge 1").  `regEx.Test` is carried out as part of `regEx.Replace` so no need to include the test, if the pattern match is found then "C6 merge 1" is replaced with the pattern value - "\b(C(?:10|[1-9])),(merge|complete framed|width),(\d+)"?

Comment: Shouldn't the `Replace` use a different string completely - regEx.Replace(strInput,"No match found text")?

Comment: I have already exlained what OP seems to need in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578867/vba-how-to-use-regular-expression-on-a-user-input-in-a-cell/50582707?noredirect=1#comment88167884_50578867). Replacement should be condtitional, Group 3 does not have to be copied back to the result always, it depends on Group 2 value. I do not have time to dig into VBA code right now. If you fix the answer, I will upvote.

Comment: Yes, was having trouble understanding your explanation _Well, it does not, but it is clear that you have not, but it is clear you are still far from what you need._ and _insert spaces between the groups unless Group 2 is complete framed, then the third group value will be omitted._.  Not sure what that means.  Your link has these examples:  `C6,merge,1, C10,merge,1, C8,merge,1` but thought shouldn't have commas between the words in the groups.  This question's starting to hurt - think I'll back away it.

Comment: @ Darren Bartrup-Cook I think the syntax needs a small change but I can`t find out where: "\b(C(?:10|[1-9])),(merge|complete framed|width),(\d+)"  - in the begining or end