# VBA Getting the correct regex syntax

Tags: regex, vba

I want to use a regex pattern to allow only specific values to be used in a cell input-only integers from 1 to 100, only these words: **merge**,**complete framed** and **width** and strings from C1 to C10.Examples: C5 width 2, C1- complete framed. Previously I used 2 variants but they were unsuccessful-one of them \b(C(?:10|[1-9])),(merge|complete framed|width),(\d+) showed some results. Any ideas how this may be changed?

Comment: Actually, [it is my regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578867/vba-how-to-use-regular-expression-on-a-user-input-in-a-cell#comment88167884_50578867). Please post the code you tried with it and explain what is wrong. I think that this is a dupe of your previous post.

Comment: Maybe this regex must be formed from the begining, not to use this old one

Comment: It is not a separate question, the answer you have received for the previous one is wrong. However, it does not mean you should ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, I understand

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. I disagree that the answer is wrong - the posted regex is wrong.  With a simplified pattern and text it finds each one.  It's what the OP wants done with the find that isn't clear - the code looks like it should replace the found string with the pattern text.  This pattern:  `^C\d\s(merge)|(width)` works for the first part.  i.e. _^C : Must start with a C._,  _\d is equivalent to [0-9]_, _\s : match a space character_ _(merge)|(width)_ match merge or width. It's just adding on the last integer, or _completed framed_ with no integer that I can't get.